# how to store pandas frame into database using to_sql

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

Am trying to store a dataframe into an oracle table using the below code
the data is inserted successfully if I omit `dtype={'PN': types.VARCHAR}`

```
merged.to_sql('table1', conn, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'PN': types.VARCHAR})
```

else it throws

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (cx_Oracle.OperationalError) ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 13
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE tabl1(
    "PN" VARCHAR, 
    "DT" DATE, 
    "COL1" FLOAT, 
    "COL2" NUMBER(19), 
    "COL3" NUMBER(19), 
    "COL4" FLOAT, 
    "COL5" FLOAT, 
    "COL6" FLOAT
)

]
```

Comment: You could try `dtype={'PN': types.VARCHAR(255)}` or some other appropriate length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle expects length for a varchar column in a "Create Table" DDL statement. As suggested by Gord ,providing a value between 1 and 255 in parenthesis will solve the issue.You can try dtype={'PN': types.VARCHAR(255)}.
If you want to know what happens in the database i have reproduced the issue on dbfiddle - Oracle 18c Express edition that you can check out.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9362757cfcb1cfc3052425190367d3d8

I wouldn't recommend using varchar for storing alphanumeric data because of following reasons :

1. Comparison Semantics Use the CHAR datatype when you require ANSI
   compatibility in comparison semantics, that is, when trailing blanks
   are not important in string comparisons. Use the VARCHAR2 when
   trailing blanks are important in string comparisons.
2. Space Usage To store data more efficiently, use the VARCHAR2
   datatype. The CHAR datatype blank-pads and stores trailing blanks up
   to a fixed column length for all column values, while the VARCHAR2
   datatype does not blank-pad or store trailing blanks for column
   values.
3. Future Compatibility The CHAR and VARCHAR2 datatypes are and will
   always be fully supported. At this time, the VARCHAR datatype
   automatically corresponds to the VARCHAR2 datatype and is reserved
   for future use.